# How to prevent mui TreeView component "stealing the event" from my other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-component

I have a TreeView component that I render next to an Options component that holds to buttons.

```
    return (
        <div
            style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "100%" }}
        >
            <Options />
            <div
                onClick={stopPropagation}
                > 
                <ThemeProvider theme={fontMuiTreeView}>
                    <TreeView
                        aria-label="rich object"
                        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
                        expanded={expandedNodes}
                        onClick={clearSelection}
                        onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
                        onNodeSelect={onSelect}
                        sx={{ height: "90vh", overflowY: 'scroll' }} 
                    >
                        {treeData.map((node) => renderTree(node))}
                    </TreeView>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Options component looking like this:

```
    const Options = () => {
        if (editable) { 
            return (
                <div

                    style={{ 
                    display: "flex", 
                    justifyContent: "center", 
                    color: "white", 
                    margin: "4px 4px", 
                    marginTop: "20px",
                    marginBottom: "25px",}}>
                        <Space>
                            <Button
                                style={{ color: "#fff", borderColor: "#192D40", backgroundColor: "#1890ff", cursor: "pointer" }}
                                onClick={onNewEntity}
                            >Add Entity</Button>
                            <Button
                                style={{ color: "#fff", borderColor: "#192D40", backgroundColor: "#1890ff", cursor: "pointer"}}
                                onClick={onNewScenario}
                            >Add Scenario</Button>
                        </Space>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

My problem is that - when I try to add a new entity using my entity button I have to click it twice if I have already highlighted one of the TreeItems in the TreeView. If I haven't highlighted anything yet the TreeItems (entities) are added, as supposed, when clicking the button. I believe the problem is due to the fact that the TreeItem is highlighted after a click and when pressing outside of the TreeView, one of the buttons, or anywhere else, clears this highlight. When the highlight is cleared the button works as expected.

I've been trying to use stopPropagation, pessist, preventDefault on the TreeItem. I've also searched for a solution that would prevent the TreeItem being highlighted in the first place.

Comment: Is `stopPropagation` a function you defined in your component?

Comment: Yes, I've defined it as so:  const stopPropagation = (e) => e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by letting the options element be a part of the TreeView. When doing this - they are part of the some propogation/bubling and it makes the options elements get the same events.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).